# Room Number Locator

Tags: code-golf

## Room Number Locator

I have come across an interesting problem solving technique at my job when given the wrong room number from a colleague for a meeting. Every now and then, while on the way to a meeting, a member on my team will send me the wrong room number, typically because they are in a rush at their desk and fat finger the wrong key.

Interestingly, upon arrival at the wrong room, I typically can guess which room they really meant by imagining a [Numeric Keypad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_keypad):

[image]

and by guessing an adjacent number they meant to press.

### Challenge

Your challenge is to write a function that takes a building office number (000-999) and outputs the possible typo solutions, **assuming your colleague only mistypes one digit.**

The following table shows which numbers are adjacent to each other on a Numeric Keypad:

```
0 -> 1,2
1 -> 0,2,4
2 -> 0,1,3,5
3 -> 2,6
4 -> 1,5,7
5 -> 2,4,6,8
6 -> 3,5,9
7 -> 4,8
8 -> 5,7,9
9 -> 6,8
```

### Input

A 3 digit number: `000-999`. Assume input of exactly 3 digits. If the number is less than 100 or less than 10, you will be given the leading zeros. (i.e. 004 & 028).

### Output

A list of possible rooms. This can be in any form you want, as long as there is a delimiter between room numbers. (i.e. space, comma, new line, etc..) If the number is less than 100 or less than 10, you can or cannot have the leading zeros as output, that is up to you. (i.e. 004 can be `004 04 4`, and 028 can be `028 28`)

Test Cases(leading zeros are optional):

```
008 -> 108, 208, 018, 028, 005, 007, 009 
123 -> 023, 223, 423, 103, 113, 133, 153, 122, 126
585 -> 285, 485, 685, 885, 555, 575, 595, 582, 584, 586, 588
777 -> 477, 877, 747, 787, 774, 778
963 -> 663, 863, 933, 953, 993, 962, 966
555 -> 255, 455, 655, 855, 525, 545, 565, 585, 552, 554, 556, 558
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes for each language wins.

Comment: [Sandbox link](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14629/76365)

Comment: Can we take input as a list of three digits (0-9)?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino As long as 3 digits are inputted into your method/function, you can do whatever form you please.

Comment: ...and this is why meeting rooms should have names.

Comment: @JonathanAllan It's a lot harder for new people to find "Dolphin Room" than "Room 218" (assuming that room numbers are assigned in order). A compromise would be alphabetically ordering the names, but then you only have 26.

Comment: How does 963->936 count as a single digit mistake?  That's a transposition error.

Comment: @KellyLowder should have been `933` so I've fixed it up.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I'll schedule a meeting in the Allegheny room. You know where that is...right? ;)

Comment: @Draco18s Not yet, and neither would I if it were a number. Names have more redundancy making for more robust communication, so unless the layout is like a hotel names make more sense.

Comment: @JonathanAllan There's a hotel I've been in a number of times (for conventions) and I always need to go to the map to find those conference rooms. They aren't even arranged in a sensible manner (ie alphabetically) and are spread across two floors. Every other place is a room-by-number which encodes its location within it (assuming you're in the right building). But yes, it is much harder to corrupt a room's *name* than you are its *number.*

Comment: Related, I once worked in IT where there was a professor who had trouble with the room technology several weeks running. He was in Bradley 210 (which I knew, Bradley being the name of the building. The building next door--Matheson--was connected via a sky bridge on the 3rd floor. Bradley was 5 stories tall, Matheson 4). He could never tell me what room he was in correctly. One time he told me he was in "Matheson 605" which patently didn't exist, and got none of the digits right.

Comment: @Draco18s I once worked in a place, with professors, and a building called Matheson, and a sky bridge on the 3rd floor between 2 buildings (where buildings had differing somewhat strange numbering since they were built into a hill), and I had to go back and see if we worked at the same place (no Bradley building where I was haha).

Comment: @briantist No hill at where I was, and I honestly forgot the name of the other building. Tried to look it up, failed, grabbed a random name (as it wasn't actually important). >> Also the Matheson building has been gone for several years now. FWIW, my place was Drexel University.

Comment: @Draco18s yeah definitely not the same place, but it was a funny set of coincidences :-p

Comment: @briantist Indeed! :D

Answer (score 13):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>112</s> 106 bytes

Recognizing that a numeric keypad is basically a 3x3 `GridGraph` with edges added for 0, we get the adjacent digits for each input digit with `AdjacencyList`.

This can be seen below:

`EdgeAdd[GridGraph[{3,3},VertexLabels->"Name",GraphLayout->"SpringEmbedding"],{0<->1,0<->2}]` yields:

[image]

Then I use `Tuples` to figure out all the possible mistakes and pick out those with exactly one error with `Select` and `EditDistance`.  By the way, this will work for longer room numbers and you can also increase the `EditDistance` parameter to allow for more than one error.  Might be able to golf this down a little further but wanted to show my approach.

```
h@u_:=Select[Tuples[AdjacencyList[EdgeAdd[GridGraph[{3,3}],{0<->1,0<->2}],#]~Join~{#}&/@u],#~EditDistance~u==1&]
```

Slightly more golfed version hardcoded to length 3 room numbers (106 Bytes).  This will output as a rank 3 list corresponding to each digit:

```
Thread/@ReplacePart[#~Table~3,{i_,i_}:>(AdjacencyList[GridGraph@{3,3}~EdgeAdd~{0<->1,0<->2},#]&/@#)[[i]]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxNC4JAGITv/Q3B0xv5gWUfhkIiRIegbovEsru0G2qi6yGW9a9vbxADM8wwPC3VUrRUK0adk/n02GU30QimyX3qGzGSgr8oEx37XNSoScmfouCcVIPi1UB7SUwMsa3BBIflMYSfR1i9ej6/VTcbz/qrfMJhLrnSJ2TQjol5yrLQr911UJ0mMvdqfBkTQACpBRNChFAwCaSQYG4AhbmF9X9HWbtfuC8)

Comment: One could also use other distance functions such as `DamerauLevenshteinDistance` instead of `EditDistance` which would also include transposition errors.

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 89 bytes

```python
lambda r:[r[:i]+[c]+r[i+1:]for i,n in enumerate(r)for c in`ord(u'ÌЋ>তŧ0ɃD'[n])`]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYsxDoIwGEZ3dvc/cQDkJwEMik1k8ha1CQhUm0ghTRmcHfUKbkbvoXFw8wjeBEti3vCSl@9rD3rXyKgfgz/xoWhKIbcEOs39ZCgWX677fV5vyhwUoYoSwTxaME9R4YWE8UaBQAlCQiW7ulK5rhzlDrkwMWtU6XT26Hn@nNLH5Xu7vu7B@7iyqWRuxvphp4czpQEGmDCkIUY4NY4xwdh4jgbjBc7@3cAYsaBVQmrQaPupjdzRbv8D)

The 1<sup>st</sup> and 5<sup>th</sup> characters may not being displayed here (browser dependent), but the full string is equivalent to `[21, 204, 1035, 62, 157, 2468, 359, 48, 579, 68]`

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 29 bytes

```
v•4TË\ªye-³—Ïʒ••Ćδn¼•S£yèʒNǝ,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/7FHDIpOQw90xh1ZVpuoe2vyoYcrh/lOTgKJAdKTt3Ja8Q3uArOBDiysPrzg1ye/4XJ3//y3NjAE)

Comment: [28 bytes in the same version as you're using](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/7FHDIqPIwzvDz@2Otj@063DnkYZHDQsPdx7ecmgFSMrEzPLCpsrDK05N8js@V@f/f0szYwA) or [27 bytes in the rewrite](https://tio.run/##ATwAw/9vc2FiaWX//3bigKIyWcO5V867Wz/CusOJxIDigKHDicO0wqjigKLFvTnCr9CyecOoypJOx50s//85NjM).

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 190 bytes

```r
function(x){l=list(c(1,2),c(0,2,4),c(0,1,3,5),c(2,6),c(1,5,7),c(2,4,6,8),c(3,5,9),c(4,8),c(5,7,9),c(6,8))
a=do.call(expand.grid, mapply(c,l[x+1],x))
a[apply(a,1,function(y){sum(x==y)==2}),]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7LCoMwFET3/Youb@hUTKp9QPMl4iLEWgJRgw@IiN@eGgJd3TNzB2bG0L6voV16PZuhJ882K62ZZtLEIRg05RAoEnDcUEYUuMfDUeKRdIE7nhGPBF4RiqSPRNLxz05KNkOmlbX08U71TfYdTYNzp5yzK2nYyl94DR@jVTLV0fsfuLJtWjryUq5MSrEz1Htwo@lnailuzGMNCz8)

---

My second attempt at CodeGolf! Pretty long, 190 bytes, but the best I could manage with R. Curious to see if others have feedback or can do better!

Comment: a whole bunch of little things: you have an extra space in the second line; abusing the precedence of `:` over `*/+-` can shave off a few bytes in the first line, getting rid of `do.call`, treating `a` as a `matrix` and transposing it saves all around 39 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HU7LDoMgELz3S3Z12whqH6Z8RY/GA8HakCASxYSm6bdT6GVm55HNrHG6H@O0W@X1YiHgxwijNw@s41R1vOCkoCJGNbWYTk7nTIxauiCxrvkXUki3LHnRJKwLXtbJPtMV8SCFh2dw0o6n16pHmKVz5g2KTB9KNlDAXOpJLeaxzxtIIQIKwYdvdKu2HibIE6r8DOMP "R – Try It Online")

Comment: You are good at this! Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org) 97 bytes

```ruby
->i{c=0;i.map{|j|[12,204,1035,26,157,2468,359,48,579,68][j].digits.map{|k|f=*i;f[c]=k;p f};c+=1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1NCoMwGET3PYXQXTuVJPrFSEgvkmbRWlKiCNKfRVDPnlqLzOrBm5nn5xZTNJd0OoexMUyHvL8O49ROlgsIVoKzgiAkOFUQpVQoqEapQFUNqZxtXX4Pj/B@/Yvd5M0haG8bZzo9ZH7WzdHweU77LFrLwKCc263AIVBsQFg2N6iwZIPlZ9VWiX5S@gI)

#### Alternatively, 94 chars but 100 bytes

```
->i{c=0;i.map{|j|"\fÌЋ\u001A\u009Dতŧ0ɃD".unpack("U*")[j].digits.map{|k|f=*i;f[c]=k;p f};c+=1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvxfaRvzX9cuszrZ1sA6Uy83saC6JqtGKSbtcM@F7phSAwNDRxBp6fJg2ZKjyw1ONrso6ZXmFSQmZ2sohWopaUZnxeqlZKZnlhRD9GbXpNlqZVqnRSfH2mZbFyik1Vona9sa1tb@V1aojI420DHQsYiN5QJzDHWMdIxhHFMdCx1TGMdcBwhhHEsdM7AysCJTkKL/AA)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (Firefox 30-57), <s>115</s> 109 bytes

```
f=([c,...a],p=``)=>c?[...(for(n of``+[12,240,1350,26,157,2468,359,48,579,68][c])p+n+a.join``),...f(a,p+c)]:[]
```

Edit: Saved 6 bytes thanks to @edc65 (although suggested `0`s now appear after other suggestions). ES6 version, <s>118</s> 112 bytes:

```js
f=([c,...a],p=``)=>c?[...[...``+[12,240,1350,26,157,2468,359,48,579,68][c]].map(n=>p+n+a.join``),...f(a,p+c)]:[]
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value).join`\n`><pre id=o>
```

Comment: I see this [for(...)] in a lot of code golfs, but I don't fully understand it, and I can't seem to find it in any documentation. Could you explain it or post a link to an explanation?

Comment: save 6 bytes `[...[12,240,1350,26,157,2468,359,48,579,78][c]+'']`

Comment: @AntonBallmaier `[for(...)]` was one of several array comprehension syntax proposals that never made it into ECMAscript. It allowed you to loop over an iterator and succinctly filter and/or map over the results. (I found it particularly useful when doing double iteration.)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 136 or 114 bytes

### ASCII version 136 bytes

```c
m[]={12,240,1350,26,157,2468,359,48,579,68},p,i,X=10;f(n){for(i=100;i;i/=X)for(p=m[n/i%X];p;p/=X)printf("%d ",n/(i*X)*(i*X)+p%X*i+n%i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3NioMwEMfPm6cIgpDYKSbamMjgPkeg9LBYlDmYhm73JD67m1R2LzP/j/kx43kex31frrdh1Q00FwW6NQqaDrSxyXcOWtPDxYGxPXRugwgEftAKJxHkOj2egpJTSEj14GUO4rBcQ02lv2HEmNP4pPCaRFHeeQGhFlR5Wb3nKZa@olMoSeK2zyLd8SDZyj7@GdXe@fkzgalAnt8ijz@vb1EUEtnGWGaWLwrizc3CpTgt3bSHMM4cwlp7iL77q0yutv0X)

### Unicode <s>114</s> 108 bytes (TiO seems to count weirdly for this)

Thanks to @ceilingcat for this version.

```c
p,i,X=10;f(n){for(i=1e3;i/=X;)for(p=L"\fðՆ\32\x9dতŧ0ɃD"[n/i%X];p;p/=X)printf("%d ",n/i/X*i*X+p%X*i+n%i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/79AJ1MnwtbQwDpNI0@zOi2/SCPT1jDV2DpT3zbCWhPEL7D1UYpJO7zhaluMsVFMhWXKg2VLji43ONnsohSdp5@pGhFrXWBdAFSuWVCUmVeSpqGkmqKgpAOU0o/QytSK0C5QBdLaeaqZmta1/9M1gGoU8jS5qrk44eoNjFMUdO2AmoAS1gogl1grFJSWFGsoKWlac9VycYH05CZm5mmA9aVrWACFgZShkTGEYWphCmGYm5tDGJZmMClTkFTtfwA)

Comment: @ceilingcat Hm. TiO says 108 bytes.

Comment: I don’t think TIO counts UTF-8 bytes correctly in C. Try changing the language to bash or something else and watch the byte count change.

Comment: @ceilingcat Yeah, was wonky locally too. Saved file is 114, true enough.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <strike>205</strike> 177 bytes

```
b->{for(int c=0;c<3;c++){char[]d=b.toCharArray();for(char e:"12,024,0135,26,157,2468,359,48,579,68".split(",")[new Byte(""+d[c])].toCharArray()){d[c]=e;System.out.println(d);}}}
```

I know it's long compared to the other answers. My excuse: it's in Java.
Oracle should rename `toCharArray` to something like `getCrs`.

### Credits

-28 characters by [**Kevin Cruijssen**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

Comment: Some small things to golf. `(String b)->` can be just `b->`, and you can remove the trailing `;`. As for actual things to golf: You only use `a` once, so you can remove `String[]a=...;` and use `"12,024,0135,26,157,2468,359,48,579,68".split(",")[...]` directly. Also, `Byte.parseByte` can be `new Byte`.  In total: [**177 bytes**](https://tinyurl.com/ybrnlqrw).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks, those are some tricks I'll have to learn :)

Comment: [Tips for golfing in Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java) and [Tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) might be interesting to read through in case you haven't yet. :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 103 bytes

thanks to @Lynn for -4 bytes.

```python
lambda n:{n[:i]+r+n[i+1:]for i,v in enumerate(n)for r in`0x134cd9a07d1e58feab643f7db24102`[int(v)::10]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzRCoMgGEbv9xT/nUVdqOUsYU/SgmwqE9ZfiIuNsWd3ya4OnI/vbO94X5End7mmh15mowHVBwflxypUOPiKqdGtAXy9g0ew@Fxs0NEWWGZ9DDjRF2vam@k1lYZZ0Tmr53PbOGlm3jLKp8FjLPZSKUbHb8q/mGOE0o7UQBhvMkQnMqSUGf35L4Ug6gSwhaMBsQZXxDL9AA)

Comment: Save 4 bytes with: ``in`0x134cd9a07d1e58feab643f7db24102`[int(v)::10]`` (I tried `int('…',36)` too but it’s one byte longer.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 35 bytes

```
ḷþị“-ⱮⱮVḟ|żṣ~ẋ³ɱgẆ’ḃ⁽¦ḳ¤$ṛ¦DŒp$¥"JẎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AV0Aov9qZWxsef//4bi3w77hu4vigJwt4rGu4rGuVuG4n3zFvOG5o37huovCs8mxZ@G6huKAmeG4g@KBvcKm4bizwqQk4bmbwqZExZJwJMKlIkrhuo7///9bMCwgMCwgOF0)

-1 thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan).

*Explanation being updated...*

Comment: I honestly have no clue about how this is parsed, let alone how it works. An explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing sorry, no time now

Comment: -1 byte: `Wẋ3` -> `ḷþ`

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>120</s> 85 + 2 (`-F`) = 87 bytes

```perl
map{@,=@F;$,[$i]=$_,say@,for(12,240,1350,26,157,2468,359,48,579,68)[$_]=~/./g;$i++}@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcexDoIwFAXQn@mg4QJt4ZUS0qRTN7@AEMKgpgnaBlyM0U/36dlOPm8rMd@W/PJwPgwCo4iTEzP25elxSdtBaehWQjUkoQ0Udf8bi4Z6tBbU9TD2OIp5cp@6qq@DiEXx9oFZSvtN@RHTfefyRJVUksvwAw)

Saved 35 bytes by borrowing an idea from @AsoneTuhid's ruby answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 93 bytes

```julia
~r=[(R=copy(r);R[j]=i;R)for i=0:9,j=1:3 if(big(1)<<(i+10r[j]))&0x502A044228550A21102B05406>0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1LT8MwEITv/RVWDpUtVurajUP6MFIRd6RQTsaHvtko2JEJolz619O4Ug/sXD7tzszWPw1tir6/RGN5ZXah/eNRLCpbO0OLShxDZGRwPoPayPmU0ZFv6cSlWC45PUiMg1GIMZ41qhXmuVKl1rhSUqJ6Rp1j8YSuTy0xhC9GnlmLgFA6YFaCgmkCDSXoBI8wKMEMivtpkHMjNkwbyXeN56lK3Dbfn@GXv61fXt/XwLLucO4mbbMhnwG73B6Kf8Hsw2didPD7/go)

- Takes a vector of digits and returns a list in the same format.
- `0x502A044228550A21102B05406` is a `UInt128` in which the `1+10j`th bit is set iff `i` is next to `j` on the numpad.
- `big(1)` is a `BigInt`. It is used to prevent overflow and uses less characters than `Int128(1)` or `UInt128(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

### SQL (SQLite), 533 bytes

```sql
with m as (select 0 as i, 1 as o union values (0,2),(1,0),(1,2),(1,4),(2,0),(2,1),(2,3),(2,5),(3,2),(3,6),(4,1),(4,5),(4,7),(5,2),(5,4),(5,6),(5,8),(6,3),(6,5),(6,9),(7,4),(7,8),(8,5),(8,7),(8,9),(9,6),(9,8))select o || substr('008', 2, 1) || substr('008', 3, 1)from m where substr('008', 1, 1) = cast(i as text)union select substr('008', 1, 1) || o || substr('008', 3, 1)from m where substr('008', 2, 1) = cast(i as text)union select substr('008', 1, 1) || substr('008', 2, 1) || o from m where substr('008', 3, 1) = cast(i as text)
```

#### Ungolfed

```sql
with m as (
    select 0 as i, 1 as o
    union
    values
    /*(0,1),*/(0,2),
    (1,0),(1,2),(1,4),
    (2,0),(2,1),(2,3),(2,5),
    (3,2),(3,6),
    (4,1),(4,5),(4,7),
    (5,2),(5,4),(5,6),(5,8),
    (6,3),(6,5),(6,9),
    (7,4),(7,8),
    (8,5),(8,7),(8,9),
    (9,6),(9,8)
)
select o || substr(s, 2, 1) || substr(s, 3, 1)
from m, t
where substr(s, 1, 1) = cast(i as text)
union
select substr(s, 1, 1) || o || substr(s, 3, 1)
from m, t
where substr(s, 2, 1) = cast(i as text)
union
select substr(s, 1, 1) || substr(s, 2, 1) || o
from m, t
where substr(s, 3, 1) = cast(i as text)
```

#### Explanation

The input is a single text row on table `t` with column `s`. My understanding is that [according to this meta answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5341/36915) this is an acceptable form of input. The input can be created as below.

```sql
drop table if exists t;
create table t (s text);
insert into t values('555'); -- Your input here
```

#### Annotated solution

```sql
with m as ( -- Using this in the "with" allows us to only type is once
    select 0 as i, 1 as o -- The first pair is here and it names the columns
    union
    values
    /*(0,1),*/(0,2),
    (1,0),(1,2),(1,4),
    (2,0),(2,1),(2,3),(2,5),
    (3,2),(3,6),
    (4,1),(4,5),(4,7),
    (5,2),(5,4),(5,6),(5,8),
    (6,3),(6,5),(6,9),
    (7,4),(7,8),
    (8,5),(8,7),(8,9),
    (9,6),(9,8)
)
select o || substr(s, 2, 1) || substr(s, 3, 1) -- concat the first wrong char with two correct chars
from m, t
where substr(s, 1, 1) = cast(i as text) -- when the first char is in the i (input) column from above
union
select substr(s, 1, 1) || o || substr(s, 3, 1)
from m, t
where substr(s, 2, 1) = cast(i as text)
union
select substr(s, 1, 1) || substr(s, 2, 1) || o
from m, t
where substr(s, 3, 1) = cast(i as text)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 117 bytes

```kotlin
mapIndexed{i,c->"12,024,0135,26,157,2468,359,48,579,68".split(",")[c-'0'].map{replaceRange(i,i+1,it+"")}}.flatMap{it}
```

### Beautified

```kotlin
mapIndexed { i, c ->
    "12,024,0135,26,157,2468,359,48,579,68"
        .split(",")[c - '0']
        .map { replaceRange(i, i + 1, it + "") }
}.flatMap { it }
```

### Test

```kotlin
fun String.f(): List<String> =
mapIndexed{i,c->"12,024,0135,26,157,2468,359,48,579,68".split(",")[c-'0'].map{replaceRange(i,i+1,it+"")}}.flatMap{it}

data class Test(val input:Int, val answers: List<Int>)

val tests = listOf(
    Test(8, listOf(108, 208, 18, 28, 5, 7, 9)),
    Test(123, listOf(23, 223, 423, 103, 113, 133, 153, 122, 126)),
    Test(585, listOf(285, 485, 685, 885, 555, 575, 595, 582, 584, 586, 588)),
    Test(777, listOf(477, 877, 747, 787, 774, 778)),
    Test(963, listOf(663, 863, 933, 953, 993, 962, 966)),
    Test(555, listOf(255, 455, 655, 855, 525, 545, 565, 585, 552, 554, 556, 558))
)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    for (r in tests) {
        val input = r.input.toString().padStart(3, '0')
        val expected = r.answers.map { it.toString().padStart(3, '0') }.sorted()
        val actual = input.f().sorted()
        if (expected != actual) {
            throw AssertionError("$input -> $actual | $expected")
        }
    }
}
```

### TIO

[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##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)

Answer (score 1):

## [T-SQL](https://www.microsoft.com/sql-server), 322 bytes

```
WITH m AS(SELECT LEFT(value,1)i,RIGHT(value,1)o FROM STRING_SPLIT('01,02,10,12,14,20,21,23,25,32,36,41,45,47,52,54,56,58,63,65,69,74,78,85,87,89,96,98',','))SELECT o+RIGHT(s,2)FROM t,m WHERE i=LEFT(s,1)UNION SELECT LEFT(s,1)+o+RIGHT(s,1)FROM t,m WHERE i=SUBSTRING(s,2,1)UNION SELECT LEFT(s,2)+o FROM t,m WHERE i=RIGHT(s,1)
```

The input is taken from the column `s` of a single-row table named `t`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t
CREATE TABLE t (s CHAR(3))
INSERT INTO t VALUES('008')
```

Ungolfed:

```
WITH m AS (
    SELECT LEFT(value,1) i, RIGHT(value,1) o
    FROM STRING_SPLIT('01,02,10,12,14,20,21,23,25,32,36,41,45,47,52,54,56,58,63,65,69,74,78,85,87,89,96,98',',')
)
SELECT o+RIGHT(s,2) FROM t,m WHERE i=LEFT(s,1)
UNION
SELECT LEFT(s,1)+o+RIGHT(s,1) FROM t,m WHERE i=SUBSTRING(s,2,1)
UNION
SELECT LEFT(s,2)+o FROM t,m WHERE i=RIGHT(s,1)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bfeb4/1)